# showDisabledChecboxes not working in ag-grid-react

Tags: ag-grid-react

I.m using react-ag-grid version 25.3.0. showDisabledCheckboxes seems to be working in version28 demo. How can I achieve this in v25.3.0

I tried using the same property and set to true in columnDef. But the disabled checkboxes are not rendering in rows.